# How do I pass along an id with an ajax call that is refreshing a partial?

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

Okay, I'm going crazy.  I'm new to python, django and ajax, and I think I understand what is happening here, but for some reason I can't figure this one out.  I am attempting to add ajax to a django website that I learned from a class that has "listings". I have a partial that contains "listing" information and I'm using ajax to refresh the partial but I'm not sure how to pass along the id of the listing I want to show.  So, I have an array of "listings" I'm attempting to view a single listing, and this works if I don't use ajax, but once ajax begins making the call it is not passing along the id.

HTML is...

```
<section id="listings-list" class="py-4">
  <div class="container" id="listing">

        {% include 'listings/partials/_listing.html' %}
  </div>
</section>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'updatelisting' listing.id %}",
      data: {
        'listing_id': listing.id
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#listing').html(data);
      }
    });
    });
    console.log('Ajax is running...  Bringing in listing partial')  
}

window.setInterval(function(){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'updatelisting' listing.id %}",
    data: {
      'listing_id': listing.id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#listing').html(data);
    }
  });
  });
  console.log('Ajax is running...  Bringing in listing partial')

}, 5000);


</script>
```

in the urls I'm collaing the updatelisting url, The urls.py is ...

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='listings'),
    path('<int:listing_id>', views.listing, name='listing'),
    url(r'^ajax/updatelistings/$', views.updatelistings, name='updatelistings'),
    url(r'^ajax/updatelisting/(?P<listing_id>)', views.updatelisting, name='updatelisting')
]
```

I'm then referencing the updatelisting view.....

```
def updatelisting(request, listing_id):
    if request.is_ajax():
        listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=listing_id)
        context = {
            'listing': listing
        }
        return render(request, 'listings/partials/_listing.html', context)
```

The above returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\listings\views.py", line 39, in updatelisting
    lesting = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=listing_id)
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 76, in get_object_or_404
    return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 404, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1340, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1367, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1301, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1155, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 72, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\disabler\Desktop\test\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1770, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.
[22/Jan/2020 11:58:53] "GET /listings/ajax/updatelisting/5?listing_id=listing HTTP/1.1" 500 20317
```

When I view the page in the browser it actually loads the correct information, but the ajax calls is receiving a 500 error as it not passing the listing_id.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question with the full traceback. Also, remove the third url (it's useless) and fix the last one (it doesn't define a proper regexp for the listing_id).

Comment: I edited the error, I got, I think that is what you mean by the full traceback.  I'm using the third url to display a list of listings and that one is working fine, the issue is I don't know how to make the forth one just list 1 listing.  regex is not a phrase I'm familiar with.  should I not have the listing id there and instead have ``` url(r'^ajax/updatelisting/$', views.updatelisting, name='updatelisting') ```

Comment: Nope, that's not the traceback. A traceback looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrYlH.png). It tells you exactly where the error happened, and shows all the functions calls that led there.

Comment: wrt/ to how to properly define a django `urlpattern`, this is fully documented. And you don't want to urls with the same name BTW (those act as identifiers so they have to be unique for your app).

Comment: okay,  I updated the error.  So, I have one url that is updatelistings and one that is updatelisting, each coorisponds to the view they reference.  I have (?P<satellite_id> because it is an attribute that the view is looking for, that it passes to a pk value.  The idea would be to pass forward the id that the satellite url/view determines.

Comment: I still can't figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated!